# Fastest way to check if string contains all substrings

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, validation

Given is an array with substrings and a string that I'm checking against if it contains all of them.

Do I have to iterate over the elements and check with indexOf >= 0 or do you have any cooler ideas? Because I have to do this task over and over again any performance benefits would help thanks in advance programming language is javascript

Comment: are all the substrings the same size by chance?

Comment: That differs but what did you think of? Just curious

Comment: it depends on the substring. you can build a regular expression and check against.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array.prototype.every(callback[, thisArg]); read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Basically, for your example it would be:

```
arr.every(function(element){
    return yourstring.indexOf(element) != -1;
});
```

The return value is either true or false, of course.

Comment: Oh, and because you actually want them all to be contained inside yourstring, you'd actually rather test it with != -1 (since indexOf returns -1 when it's not found). I'll edit this right now.

Comment: Is that any better than checking >= 0?

Comment: Well, performance-wise != and >= don't really make a measurable difference, so choose whatever you find more readable and intuitive.
I edited that one because I compared it to zero with == 0 (I forgot that in Javascript -1 is returned for no match) which was obviously a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a cool idea and really have a lot of these substrings to test for?

It then will be a good idea performance-wise to build a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) for your string, which has a lookup complexity only depending on the substring size.

You'll get down the complexity from `O(len(string) * len(substring) * N_substrings)`<sup>1</sup> of the naive solution (like @BaneBojanić's one) to `O(len(string) + len(substring) * N_substrings)`.

<sub>1: Assuming `len(string) * len(substring)` complexity for `indexOf`, it might be better than [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Na.C3.AFve_string_search) though</sub>

Comment: Not that many but its a repetetive task could you explain that any further for me? :-)

Comment: @Skeec: Have you checked out the wikipedia link already? I'm not going to repeat everything from there :-)

Comment: Well I think I got it

Comment: Will it be expensive to always create a new suffix tree because its not always the same string

Comment: If your array of substrings to check for is large, yes, probably it's still a good idea. Creating the tree is not *that* expensive. If you are looking for actual speed, there's nothing you can do but implement multiple solutions and benchmark them with your actual data.

Comment: @Skeec Just how large do you expect this array to be?

Comment: Okay I will check this out but I still didnt get it in detail this mathematic algorithms can be very confusing just give me some time :-)

Comment: @Skeec: Of course you won't have to implement it yourself (unless your looking for experience), [there are multiple libraries available](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+suffix+tree) that provide an implementation.

Comment: Its for a search input so if you type 'sam white plumber'  the array would have 3 elements and I dont expect that going more into detail makes sense im quering against 7400 rows of data

Comment: Oh thanks experience is good I dont want to load a lot of code in afraid that it will slow the process down

Comment: @Skeec: Well that's exactly the opposite problem - you have a lot of constant data (the 7400 rows) and the substrings as dynamic input (the search terms). No, a suffix tree won't help you here. You might want to ask a new question where you state this as your actual problem.

Comment: It worth mentioning that it is `O(n^2)` by the space.

Comment: Actually I get each row back just needed a way to check the input against these rows

Comment: @zerkms: What is `n`? Suffix trees take `O(string_length)` space.

Comment: @Skeec: If you can't avoid acting on each row individually, there's not much you'd need to optimise for just three search terms. Go for the naive solution.

Comment: @Bergi I believe it takes `O(string_length ^ 2)` space "The total length of all the strings on all of the edges in the tree is O(n^2)"

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, but that's unnecessary, as mentioned in the next sentence.

Comment: Great answer, but how do you actually implement this in practice in javascript?

Comment: @zero_cool Do you have a particular problem? Then please ask a new question about your implementation attempt. Otherwise, just look at [various examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=suffix+trie+javascript).

Comment: @Bergi A jsfiddle with a searchable suffix tree in vanilla javascript would be amazing. Where does such a rare animal exist?

Comment: I did find this one - it's in angular, but with a little work, I can get it vanilla: http://jsfiddle.net/rocketegg0/58rne23o/

Answer (score 0):

You need an algorithm that search a [finite set of patterns in one text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns).

The most known one with numerous implementations is [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).